# why does google request apple-app-site-association from every domain on the server?

Tags: google, url, spam, apple

I received the following in my log:

[Mon Oct 05 11:04:35 2015] [error] [client 66.249.75.xxx] File does not exist: /path/to/user/public_html/apple-app-site-association

xxx in the log is a number between 11 and 245. Also, the source IP is    66.249.69.yyy where yyy is 7, 59, and 94.

Based on the entry, it appears google is trying to look up http://www.example.com/apple-app-site-association where www.example.com is every domain name that the server manages including the server IP address itself.

Why would google randomly search for apple-app-site-association?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html it seems that the URL in question is supposed to be a JSON file linking paths on your website, back to your iOS app (when such an association exists, naturally).

I got some hits too which left and wondering the same as you.

My apple-app-site-association has also been receiving the occasional hit (or should I say 404!) by Googlebot recently although the file doesn't - and has never - existed.

My guess is that it's just google extending it's mapping to include information on associations between websites and specific iOS apps.